# Angular Material - align checkbox to the left

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am creating a simple login form, and there is a checkbox. By default, the checkbox is not aligned to the left with the other controls. Is this expected, I mean by the material design?  Is there a way of aligning the checkbox with the other controls?

The form design:
[image]

The code of the form:

```
<mat-card [formGroup]="form" class="custom">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Email address</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="userName">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
        <input type="password" matInput formControlName="password">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-checkbox formControlName="rememberMe" matInput>Remember me</mat-checkbox>

    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onLoginClick()" [disabled]="!form.valid">
        Log in
    </button>

    <button mat-raised-button (click)="onGoogleLogin()">
        Login with Google
    </button>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Read the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api). You see in the API that you have a property (the marked as `@Input`): `labelPosition`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a class with a style override to align the checkbox with your text fields.

```
mat-checkbox.aligned {
  margin-left: -8px !important;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mkkf5p?file=src%2Fstyles.scss